# full calendar showing events twice

Tags: fullcalendar, spservices

I have the spservices and fullcalendar working with SharePoint Online 2013.  It pulls in the events.  I have referenced the following files and code listed below.  Any help on what I am missing would be appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Custom2013/css/fullcalendar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Custom2013/css/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom2013/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom2013/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom2013/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom2013/js/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Custom2013/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        // Assign buttons to the header of the calendar. See FullCalendar documentation for details.
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
        },
        defaultView: "month", // Set the default view to month
        firstHour: "6", // Set the first visible hour in agenda views to 5 a.m.
        // Set the height of the calendar in pixels
        weekMode: "liquid", // Only display the weeks that are needed
        editable: false, // Set the calendar to read-only; events can't be dragged or resized

        // Add events to the calendar. This is where the "magic" happens!
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        // Create an array to hold the events.
            var events = [];
        // Set the date from which to pull events based on the first visible day in the current calendar view. For a month view, this will usually be several days into the previous month. We can use FullCalendar's built-in getView method along with the formatDate utility function to create a date string in the format that SharePoint requires. It must be in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ. Due to time zone differences, we will omit everything after the day.
            var startDate = moment().format($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').intervalstart, "u").split("T")[0];
            // Get the current view of the calendar (agendaWeek, agendaDay, month, etc.). Then set the camlView to the appropriate value to pass to the web service. This way we will only retrieve events needed by the current view (e.g. the agendaWeek view will only retrieve events during the current week rather than getting all events for the current month).
            var calView = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
            var camlView = "";

            switch (calView) {
            case "basicWeek":
                camlView = "<Week />";
                break;
            case "basicDay":
                camlView = "<Week />";
                break;
            default:
                // Default to month view
                camlView = "<month />";
                break;
            }
            // Make the web service call to retrieve events.
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "Stores Calendar",
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Add_x0020_to_x0020_Workload_x002' />" +
            "</ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query>" +
            "<Where>" +
                "<Eq>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='Add_x0020_to_x0020_Workload_x002' />" +
                    "<Value Type='Choice'>" + "Yes" + "</Value>" +
                "</Eq>" +
              "<And>" +
                 "<DateRangesOverlap>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
                        "<month />" +
                    "</Value>" +
                 "</DateRangesOverlap>" +
              "</And>" +          
            "</Where>" +
            "<OrderBy>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" +
        "</Query>",
    CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions>" +
            "<CalendarDate>" + start + "</CalendarDate>" +
            "<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>" +
            "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
        "</QueryOptions>",
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                var events = [];
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                var $node = $(this),
                fADE = $node.attr("ows_fAllDayEvent") || 0,
                thisADE = (fADE === 0),
                thisID = $node.attr("ows_ID"),
                sepID = thisID.indexOf(';#'),
                thisTitle = $node.attr("ows_Title"),
                thisRecurrence = $node.attr("ows_fRecurrence"),
                thisDesc = $node.attr("ows_Description");
            if (sepID != -1) thisID = thisID.substring(0,sepID);
            var thisUrl = "DispForm.aspx?ID=" + thisID,
                thisClass = thisTitle.replace(" ","").substr(0,10).replace(",","").replace(" ","") + thisID,
                thisRD = $node.attr("ows_RecurrenceData");                                                        
 
            // if working with FullCalendar or building an events object for another purpose...
            events.push({
                title: thisTitle,
                start: $node.attr("ows_EventDate"),
                end: $node.attr("ows_EndDate"),
                allDay: thisADE,
                url: thisUrl,
                description: $(thisDesc).text()
                        });
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```